# Github commiter identity

Tags: git, github

I have my project on github and I messed something up with the identities of commiter.

I'm the only commiter but I think I changed something, so now when I commit it shows my name but as a different user as before (the one who created github account with my avatar).

I moved to new PC and here I use HTTPS with credentials instead of SSH used before.

I also maybe changed my git config file id.

When I create a readme on github I get correct user, but when I push something from my PC I get another user.

Should I set SSH on new PC also, or should I fix something in git config?

You can check what is going on here: https://github.com/croraf/rafacoin/commits/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub tries to associate new commits by comparing the email address of the commit with the ones linked to your account (https://github.com/settings/emails).

So check what address you use locally to commit:

```
git config --get user.name                                                                                                                                
git config --get user.email
```

If it isn't your name and email change it with:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "Your EMail"
```